# View retrieval mixin that does not involve any Django model

Tags: django-rest-framework

I found myself writing this view mixin for Django Rest Framework the other day:

```py
class SerializerRetrievalMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin that just passes request query params to a serializer, validates
    and returns the response.

    Implementing classes must have a `serializer_class` attribute.
    """

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=request.query_params,
            context={'request': request},
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Is there anything like this already in Django Rest Framework? I found that `CreateAPIView` works quite well with POST, but is there anything similar for GET? `RetrieveAPIView` is based around there being a Django model involved, but in my case there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `get` method code, you'll see that it calls `get_object` to retrieve the object to serialize. So if you are not working with models then you can override your get object to return the object or whatever data should be serialized and sent as response. Of course, you can't use a model serializer in this case as it expects model objects.

Comment: I know, I have tried just returning `self.request.query_params` in the `get_object` method but that doesn't work when e.g. the serializer has an optional field with a default value and the query params don't contain that field. This seems like a pretty simple and common use case, so I was wondering if there is any built-in way to support it.

Comment: Another thing that's missing from this method is that it never actually validates the data.

Comment: To be honest, I don't actually see the work your endpoint does as it just returns the query parameters that was sent in the request. In any case, post your serializer code as the validation is done there. Also post the errors you get

Comment: In the mixin I posted in my question note that I'm doing `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` before returning the serializer data. The validation step also populates a read-only field in my serializer which is returned to the user. For secrecy reasons I cannot post the actual serializer code and frankly I don't think it's relevant to the question.

Comment: `serilaizer.is_valid` merely calls other methods in the serializer to validate the data and it strictly depends on the serializer definition. So I'm not sure why you think the serializer is not relevant here but anyway it's all up to you. I have tried to offer the best suggestion I could based on the info you posted. Unfortunately, I can't help without more info. Hope you do find a way to solve your problem